# Hive ACID table is throwing error FAILED: UnsupportedOperationException openTxn is not supported in aws EMR

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I tried creating Hive ACID table in **AWS EMR 6.3.0**. I have set the necessary parameters to enable ACID properties on the hive managed table. After setting the properties and when creating the table I encountered the following error   **FAILED: UnsupportedOperationException openTxn is not supported**

Please find the steps followed by me

Step 1:

```
set hive.support.concurrency = true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager =org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on = true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads = 1;
```

Step2:

```
hive>
    >
    > create table Sample_Table2(
    > col1 Int,
    > col2 String,
    > col3 String)
    > clustered by (col3) into 3 buckets
    > stored as orc
    > TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');
FAILED: UnsupportedOperationException openTxn is not supported
```

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue... Opened a support case with AWS Support... Will post an answer if resolved.